# Build Failed with Semantic Issue Property 'expiredPermissions' not found on object of type 'FBSDKAccessToken *'

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Building is not possible - Build fails with Semantic Issue:

> "Property 'expiredPermissions' not found on object of type
>   'FBSDKAccessToken *'; did you mean 'declinedPermissions'?" in
>   RCTFBSDKAccessToken.m

This is the version I use

```
package.json

"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.1"
```

Manual sdk installation with facebook sdk version: `FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.44.0`

Answer (score 3):

I find that install the last Facebook SDK through CocaPods resolve the issue:

Add these lines in your Pod file

```
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

And then in your project directory's ios folder run

```
pod install
```

Comment: I am not using pod what should I do. Please help any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try to update to the latest sdk version, This might resolve your issue @AhteshamShah